# Converting SQL Server Express To SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, converters

I have created a program that uses SQL Server Express as its database.

Now I want to convert the database to SQL Server.

How can I do this?

Comment: SQL Server Express ***IS*** SQL Server - no "conversion" necessary. Just simply **(1)** backup your database in SQL Server Express, and then **(2)** restore that backup on your "full" SQL Server instance. You need to make sure that the **version** of the target platform is **at least** as new as the SQL Server Express you're coming from - you **cannot** "go back" in versions (e.g. backup from SQL Server **2014** Express, and then restore to SQL Server **2012**)

Answer (score 2):

There is no converter or something needed.

You just have to select your database in your Management Studio (Express) and detach it from your SQL Server Express instance.

Then connect to your SQL Server and attach the database with a right-click on `Databases -> Attach`.